# OV code signing certificate provider without personal address on certificate?

Tags: certificate, code-signing, certificate-authority

Which CA can provide me with personal (OV) code signing certificate that will not include my address? Some include only `city` but not everyone lives in a big city to feel comfortable with that. Additionally, the verification process should allow for document scans without notary verification.

Comment: What you want doesn’t exist since it would defeat the purpose of an extended validation certificate

Comment: Unless, of course, the certificate is in the name of a company...

Comment: I don’t agree. I don’t need EV,but OV cert. The CA holds my information and if the certificate would be used to sign anything malicious, the access to full data and complete revokation is 1 email away. There is really no need to dox myself with every exe that I sign. When you meet people on the street, you don’t wear your passport taped to the forehead. The most important part of the certificate are the public key and the issuer data, not the name and address of cert holder. I already found the CA that does not require notarized documents. They do however include your address to the cert data.

Comment: There is no sense even getting OV certificate if I would need to provide pretty much everything if I could just go for the EV then and get instant trust rank for a few 100 bucks more.

Comment: @miran80 Did you find any solution? I also don't want to publish my address on the OV cert. Notarized documents is okay for me. Thanks.